# Bucket sort has uniformly distributed data

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Implementation of bucket sort is mainly useful when input is uniformly distributed over a range. So the ques here is what is the significance of having input data uniformly distributed for applying bucket sort? What happens if this does not hold?

Comment: In the extreme case, if all numbers are very close, they'll fall into the same bucket, and bucketing will gain you nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bucket sort will be slower if the data distribution is highly non-uniform.  The primary advantage of bucket sort over other sorting algorithm is that it is faster when the data is uniformly distributed; so if the data is highly non-uniformly  distributed, the advantages of bucket sort may evaporate.